# MIDI Program Change event

Tags: binary, midi, binary-data

Please take a look at [Midi Event Commands](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm#midi_event_commands), where it's explained that some events like Program Change take only one parameter.

My question is then what do you send along with this event's 2nd parameter's byte, is it 0x00? or you just entirely omit it from the event which doesn't really make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all MIDI messages are 3 bytes long.  Some are only two, and program change is one of them.  For these messages, there is no second data byte.